# Establishing patterns, hotspots and clusters?

Tags: raster, clustering, multi-criteria-analysis

As a crime analyst you need to establish a few maps that would help police to do targeted patrols, I've given data of suburbs, roads, incidents, boundaries.

How can I establish patterns, hotspots and clusters?

Comment: What software suite do you want to use? Also, your question is pretty broad in scope; can you make it more specific and indicate what research you have done?

Comment: Is this a question from homework or schoolwork? It's okay if so, but it is best to identify it as such.

Comment: For a little background to make yor question better.. Search heat map here and other places

Comment: have a look at Mapping and Analysing Crime Data: Lessons from Research and Practice
 edited by Alex Hirschfield, Kate Bowers CRC Press, 2004

Answer (score 2):

The best applied application for performing hotspot and cluster analysis is CrimeStat.
You will find all the needed data [here:](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/). Download it and use the manual to see what you can perform there.

Basically you will need a shapefile with the locations of the crimes, which you load in the first tab:

[image: Data Setup tab]

after which you will have access to the other tabs where you set up the analysis parameters, and use the Save... buttons to generate the files with the results.

[image: Data Analysis tab]

I do not know what you mean by patterns, but CrimeStat also have a module for Spatial Modelling and Crime travel demand, so please read the docs and the papers behind the software and see if they match your needs.